# How to arrange a List of Objects into organized Map of object property key & object list value? | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, filter

What is the quickest & most efficient way (memory efficiency) to filter a list of objects into a map with each unique object property being a key with a list of objects with matching object property?

I can't figure out how to do this without using lots of memory and duplicating the main list. In practice this initial list could have thousands of entries.

```
void main() {
  
  List<Car> cars = [
    Car('BMW', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 4),
    Car('Mercedes', 2),
    Car('Ferarri', 2),
    Car('Ferarri', 4),
    Car('BMW', 6),
    Car('BMW', 2),
    Car('BMW', 4),
    Car('McLaren', 3),
  ];
  
  Map<String, List<Car>> organizedCars = {};
  
  for (Car car in cars) {
    ???
  }
  
}

class Car {
  String name;
  int passangers;
  
  Car(this.name, this.passangers);
}
```

Required output:

```
Map<String, List<Car>> organizedCars = {
'BMW': [
    Car('BMW', 6),
    Car('BMW', 5),
    Car('BMW', 2),
    Car('BMW', 4),
    ],
'Mercedes': [
    Car('Mercedes', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 4),
    Car('Mercedes', 2),
    ],
etc...
};
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `.update` on `organizedCars`? `organizedCars.update(car.name, (list) => list..add(car), ifAbsent: () => [car]);`

Comment: I would like to see this implemented if you don't mind. It looks useful and I've never heard of the update method until now. Would you mind adding an answer implementing my example? Also looks very similar to @Rahul s answer. using .fold on the list. How do the guts of these two differ if using .update on the initially empty Map?

Comment: Just replace the `???` in your code with the code I provided.

Comment: Both solutions do essentially the same thing. `.fold` is the functional programming approach, and it also starts with an initially empty map and calls `.update` to add in all the data. `.fold` is just used as an alternative to the for loop in his solution.

Comment: Oh I see now. Makes more sense, good to have options. Thanks for the simple explanation. It .update works just as nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fold` method to group the items together.

Here is one impelementation:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  List<Car> cars = [
    Car('BMW', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 4),
    Car('Mercedes', 2),
    Car('Ferarri', 2),
    Car('Ferarri', 4),
    Car('BMW', 6),
    Car('BMW', 2),
    Car('BMW', 4),
    Car('McLaren', 3),
  ];

  final orgnizedCar = cars.fold(
      HashMap<String, List<Car>>(),
      (previousValue, element) => previousValue
        ..update(
          element.name,
          (value) => value..add(element),
          ifAbsent: () => [element],
        ));

  print(orgnizedCar);
}

class Car {
  String name;
  int passangers;

  Car(this.name, this.passangers);

  @override
  String toString() => "Car('$name', $passangers)";
}
```

Output:

```
{
    Ferarri: [Car('Ferarri', 2), Car('Ferarri', 4)], 
    BMW: [Car('BMW', 5), Car('BMW', 6), Car('BMW', 2), Car('BMW', 4)], 
    Mercedes: [Car('Mercedes', 5), Car('Mercedes', 4), Car('Mercedes', 2)], 
    McLaren: [Car('McLaren', 3)]
}
```

Output is formatted as it was single line in console it would not look pretty here.

Answer (score 1):

For `Map`s that don't allow nullable values, I prefer using `(map[key] ??= []).add(...)`, which is more succinct (and which I think is more elegant) than using `Map.update(..., ifAbsent: ...)`.  It looks up the `List` associated with the `Map` key, initializing the `Map` value to an empty `List` if the lookup fails, and then unconditionally appends an element to the found `List`.

```dart
void main() {
  List<Car> cars = [
    Car('BMW', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 4),
    Car('Mercedes', 2),
    Car('Ferarri', 2),
    Car('Ferarri', 4),
    Car('BMW', 6),
    Car('BMW', 2),
    Car('BMW', 4),
    Car('McLaren', 3),
  ];

  Map<String, List<Car>> organizedCars = {};

  for (Car car in cars) {
    (organizedCars[car.name] ??= []).add(car);
  }

  print(organizedCars);
}

class Car {
  String name;
  int passangers;

  Car(this.name, this.passangers);

  @override
  String toString() => "Car('$name', $passangers)";
}
```

Which will print (after some reformatting):

```
{
  BMW: [
    Car('BMW', 5),
    Car('BMW', 6),
    Car('BMW', 2),
    Car('BMW', 4)
  ],
  Mercedes: [
    Car('Mercedes', 5),
    Car('Mercedes', 4),
    Car('Mercedes', 2)
  ],
  Ferarri: [
    Car('Ferarri', 2),
    Car('Ferarri', 4)
  ],
  McLaren: [
    Car('McLaren', 3)
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thats handy to know, thanks for the answer